# Logic about return in rust

Tags: rust

It's easy rust code, which is from rustbook on rust website.
In rust if line is without ";" at the end it works like a return.

1. In this case line
   `break counter * 2;`
   has this and return value, why?
2. If I drop this ";" in thia line i get the same result, why?
3. Even if I add this ";" to the next line i mean `};` i get the same result, why?

I try to understand it, but can't catch this logic.

```
fn main() {
    let mut counter = 0;

    let result = loop {
        counter += 1;

        if counter == 10 {
            break counter * 2;
        }
    };

    println!("Zmienna result wynosi {result}");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break EXPRESSION`, when reached, [immediately terminates the closest `loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#break-expressions)<sup>1</sup> (that is moves the program flow to just after the loops closing brace `}`) and the whole `loop {…}` evaluates to the value of `EXPRESSION` (always `counter * 2` = `10 * 2` = `20` in your example), what comes after it does not matter at all.

---

<sup>1: or `for` or `while` but they don't allow `break`ing with expressions so that'd result in a compiler error</sup>